# MongoDB - Best practices for Feed restructuring in a social app database

Tags: database-design, mongodb

I have a social app, where users can post to the school they chose on registration. Each post can have a `hashtag` and a `school` (all pointers, (`hashtag` is optional, `school` is not)).

Users see posts based on `school` or `hashtag`. Now we want to introduce a new feature, **Polls**. Polls are another type of post... Users will be seeing them in their feed among other posts! Besides other properties, they too have a `hashtag` and a `school`.

Right now when a user asks for posts, I'm just making a query to the `Post` collection, comparing only the `school` or `hashtag` field (depending on the screen they're at). So if they're on the **Home** screen, I'm going to have something like:

> find all documents in `Post`, where `school` equals `<some_value>`

And if they are on the **Hashtag** screen, we have something like:

> find all documents in `Post`, where `hashtag` equals `<some_value>`

Since we are going to have the new `Poll` collection, I'm wondering what implementation would be best... Here's what I have so far:

**1st implementation**

We keep the posts query as is and we add another one, pretty much the same, for the polls and we combine the results. Have in mind here, that our app fetches data with pagination, so we bring the posts 20-by-20. I'm saying this because in case we have a page and the responses of the 2 queries bring 20 documents each, we'll have to compare dates to know what the response should be... eg 16 posts and 4 polls.

**2nd (and last) implementation**

We create a new collection, `Feed`, which would combine both collections and it would look like this:

```
Feed

post: <Pointer to Post>
poll: <Pointer to Poll>
creator: <Pointer to User> // we need this for block checking or if you open your profile
school: <Pointer to School>
hashtag: <Pointer to Hashtag>
```

Every time a post or poll will be created, their triggers will create a `Feed` document, with all the necessary values.

I believe the second solution is the best, as it is much cleaner than the first. I also think they're pretty much the same complexity-wise.

Any ideas on which one is better? If you have any other implementation to suggest, **please** do so!

NOTE: All collections are indexed.